# Field 'password' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Laravel errors out on Facebook login with following message:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value
```

If I set mysql db col to allow NULL and default NULL it works fine.

The same db with the script works fine on multiple other machines. Why? what's wrong with my mysql installation? (mysql versions on different machines are same, ubuntu mysql works fine, mac mysql fails, multiple homestead mysql on mac work fine too)

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `activate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avatar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sms_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_verify` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: A social login wouldn't produce a password, so there'd be nothing to store in that field.  If the field isn't nullable and doesn't have a default, that would produce an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your other servers are (mis)configured to convert `NULL` values into empty strings, while this other server is configured to use [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict):

> Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in
>   data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be
>   invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data
>   type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing
>   when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL
>   column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a
>   NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.)

The proper fix would really be the one you mention: if the column is not mandatory, it shouldn't be `NOT NULL` in the first place.